# Android Splash screen Firebase synchronization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, splash-screen, firebase-storage

I have created a splash screen for my android app,

in this activity I need to download some sounds from firebase storage and synchronized my local database with firebase realtime database.

but when I start the app, I see in my log the synchronization with firebase continue after the splash screen and the data is not in the locale database when the mainActivity is launch.
Who to do for start the MainActivity aft the firebase synchronization is completed.

My code :

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+getString(R.string.folder_name));
    if(!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    new DataSyncFb(this).execute();
}



public class DataSyncFb extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {


    private Context context;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;


    public DataSyncFb(final Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("DataSincFB", "onPreExecute");
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("categorie");
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    List<String> listCat = db.getAllCategoriesId();
                    List<String> listSounds = db.getAllSoundsId();
                    Log.i("test", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                    Gson test = new Gson();

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(test.toJson(dataSnapshot.getValue()));

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject cat = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nom = cat.getString("nom");
                        String id = cat.getString("id");
                        if (!listCat.contains(id)) {
                            db.addCategorie(nom, id);
                        }

                        JSONArray sounds = cat.getJSONArray("son");
                        Log.i("cat", sounds.toString());
                        for (int j = 0; j < sounds.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject sound = sounds.getJSONObject(j);
                            String soundId = sound.getString("id");
                            if (!listSounds.contains(soundId)){
                                //downloadFile(sound.getString("lien"));


                                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://soundbox-a6dd8.appspot.com");
                                StorageReference  islandRef = storageRef.child(sound.getString("lien")+".mp3");

                                File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getString(R.string.folder_name));
                                if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                                    rootPath.mkdirs();
                                }

                                final File localFile = new File(rootPath,sound.getString("lien")+".mp3");

                                islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " +localFile.toString());
                                        //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
                                    }
                                });

                                db.addSound(soundId, sound.getString("nom"), sound.getString("lien") ,id);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("sound", String.valueOf(db.getAllSound()));
                    Log.i("Firebase", jsonArray.toString());
                    Log.i("Firebase", String.valueOf(db.getAllCategories()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.i("DataSyncFB", "onPostExecute");
        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        // close this activity
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should need custom callback for your asynctask to be triggered when all your download tasks are finished. Here's the modified code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"+getString(R.string.folder_name));
    if(!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    new DataSyncFb(this, new DataSyncFb.OnTaskFinishedCallback(

        @Override
        public void onTaskFinished() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    )).execute();
}



public class DataSyncFb extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    // Custom callback
    public interface OnTaskFinishedCallback {
        public void onTaskFinished();
    }

    private Context context;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private OnTaskFinishedCallback callback;


    public DataSyncFb(final Context context, OnTaskFinishedCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i("DataSincFB", "onPreExecute");
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("categorie");
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    List<String> listCat = db.getAllCategoriesId();
                    List<String> listSounds = db.getAllSoundsId();
                    Log.i("test", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                    Gson test = new Gson();

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(test.toJson(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                    int totalDownloadCounter = 0;
                    int downloadCounter = 0;
                    // Determine how much files you should download first
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject cat = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray sounds = cat.getJSONArray("son");
                        for (int j = 0; j < sounds.length(); j++){
                            String soundId = sound.getString("id");
                            if (!listSounds.contains(soundId)) {
                                totalDownloadCounter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject cat = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nom = cat.getString("nom");
                        String id = cat.getString("id");
                        if (!listCat.contains(id)) {
                            db.addCategorie(nom, id);
                        }

                        JSONArray sounds = cat.getJSONArray("son");
                        Log.i("cat", sounds.toString());
                        for (int j = 0; j < sounds.length(); j++){
                            JSONObject sound = sounds.getJSONObject(j);
                            String soundId = sound.getString("id");
                            if (!listSounds.contains(soundId)){
                                //downloadFile(sound.getString("lien"));

                                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://soundbox-a6dd8.appspot.com");
                                StorageReference  islandRef = storageRef.child(sound.getString("lien")+".mp3");

                                File rootPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getString(R.string.folder_name));
                                if(!rootPath.exists()) {
                                    rootPath.mkdirs();
                                }

                                final File localFile = new File(rootPath,sound.getString("lien")+".mp3");

                                islandRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file created  created " +localFile.toString());
                                        downloadCounter++;
                                        //  updateDb(timestamp,localFile.toString(),position);
                                        if (downloadCounter == totalDownloadCounter) {
                                            callback.onTaskFinished();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        Log.e("firebase ",";local tem file not created  created " +exception.toString());
                                        downloadCounter++;
                                        if (downloadCounter == totalDownloadCounter) {
                                            callback.onTaskFinished();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                                db.addSound(soundId, sound.getString("nom"), sound.getString("lien") ,id);

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("sound", String.valueOf(db.getAllSound()));
                    Log.i("Firebase", jsonArray.toString());
                    Log.i("Firebase", String.valueOf(db.getAllCategories()));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.i("DataSyncFB", "onPostExecute");

    }
```

Comment: but i download many sound so i make the download inside a For, so i can't move the code from onPost to onSuccess